# How to exclude some files and folder in telescope?

Tags: neovim, plugin-telescope

I want to exclude `package-lock.json` and `lazy-lock.json` on `telescope` but I cant make it work.
Both files are not included in `.gitignore` but I don't want to search on them.
This my config for telescope

```lua
telescope.setup({
    defaults = {
        prompt_prefix = "❯ ",
        selection_caret = "❯ ",
        file_ignore_patterns = {
            "node_modules/.*",
            "%.env",
            "yarn.lock",
            "package-lock.json",
            "lazy-lock.json",
            "init.sql",
            "target/.*",
            ".git/.*",
        },
        mappings = {
            n = {
                ["<M-p>"] = act_layout.toggle_preview,
            },
            i = {
                ["<esc>"] = act.close,
                ["<M-p>"] = act_layout.toggle_preview,
                ["<C-h>"] = "which_key",
            },
        },
    },
    pickers = {
        buffers = {
            mappings = {
                i = {
                    ["<C-d>"] = act.delete_buffer + act.move_to_top,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    extensions = {
        file_browser = {
            path = "%:p:h",
        },
    },
})
```

But its still keep search on `*-lock.json`.
What is the correct way to exclude it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash in the string is interpreted as quantifier so I need to escape them.
For example the `package-lock.json` should be `package%-lock.json`.